# Почему это работает в С++

Tags: c#, c++

**C#:**

```
public class A
    {}

    class HelloWorld {
      static void Main() {
        A a;
        a;
      }
    }
```

> main.cs(12,5): error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

**C++:**

```
class A
{};

int main()
{
  A a;
  a;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: а почему оно не должно работать?

Comment: Потому что C# и C++ - *разные* языки программирования. (И что в данном случае имеется виду под "работает"?)

Comment: @AnT, "компилируется" ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Потому что Си++ позволяет в качестве statement использовать любой expression, а C# - нет.

Кстати, js тоже позволяет:

```js
function f(x) {
  var y;
  x + y;
  return x;
}

console.log(f(42));
```